# Is there a way to remove hyperlinks from objects on django admin changelist that user does not have permission to change?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am currently utilizing the `has_change_permission` hook in my custom django admin class to implement a simple form of row-level permissions and determine whether a non-superuser can edit a particular object, like so:

```
def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None or request.user.is_superuser or (obj and not obj.superuser_only): # (my model has a 'superuser_only' flag that gets set via fixtures, but its beyond the scope of this question) 
            return True
        return False
```

This works well enough: all objects are shown to a user, but if they click on an object that they don't have permission to edit then they are taken to my 403 page, presumably because PermissionDenied is raised. However, giving them a hyperlink to a permission denied page doesn't seem ideal for this case; I would like to show the objects but not provide any hyperlinks to the edit page on the list page (in addition to raising PermissionDenied if they tried to manually use the URL for the object).  Is there a straightforward hook for removing these hyperlinks without a horrendous hack?  I'm an experienced django developer so if you can point me in the right direction (if any exists), I'll be able to implement the details or determine that its not worth it for now.

Comment: Have you looked at [ModelAdmin.get_changelist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist)?

Comment: @AdamTaylor I've looked at it, and looked at the default class and not seen anything jump out at me that I could override to acheive what I'm asking.  Any specific recommendations?  Maybe I'm not THAT experienced of a django developer :)

Comment: Sorry, I must have been out of it when I made that suggestion. I looked into it more tonight and couldn't find a straightforward way to do it. The only way I can see this being accomplished is by monkey patching the `django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py` file's `results` function. You would save the value of `cl.list_display_links` and then, in each `for` loop, set it to its original value and change it as needed. This is very hacky, though, and you would only want the patched version of that function to be used on that specific model. Yuck. Sorry I can't think of something better!

Comment: @AdamTaylor Yeah, I'd poked around and was hoping there might be something I'd missed. Regardless, thanks! If this becomes higher priority I'll probably end up using your helpful suggestion unless something else pops out to me when I start looking at it.  (I wonder if I could somehow get information about whether the permission is set on to the page in a hidden form field or something, and then just jquery away the hyperlink...)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this in a fairly straightforward way by overwriting the default get_list_display_links function in the ModelAdmin class (in my admin.py file):

```
def get_list_display_links(self, request, list_display):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        if self.list_display_links or not list_display:
            return self.list_display_links
        else:
            # Use only the first item in list_display as link
            return list(list_display)[:1]
    else:
        # Ensures that no hyperlinks appear in the change list for non-superusers
        self.list_display_links = (None, )
        return self.list_display_links
```

Note that my code maintains the hyperlink for superusers. You can easily just use the latter part of the function if you don't want to make this distinction.

Comment: While I appreciate the response, (and I was excited to see it after all this time, since I've never resolved this issue), unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. If you read the question closely you'll note that I want some rows to have links and some rows not to have links, based on whether or not an object's "superuser_only" field is True. I don't see any possibility for row-level control in get_list_display_links. Your implementation either removes ALL links or leaves them all, based on the user's superusers status, which doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that! Only thing I can think of is overriding this template file directly by creating /templates/admin/[your app]/[your model]/change_list.html and modifying it to take your superuser_only property into account when creating the hyperlinks. Fairly hacky though, and similar to what the other guy suggested above.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good suggestion. Users haven't complained for more than a year so I'll probably leave it as a low priority project for now.